# Loop insert query into table and its relationel table

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

I have 3 tables called `Tweets`, `Teams` and `Tweet_contain`. What I'm trying is to check whether a set of tweets contain the teams twitter username. If they do that the tweet should be added to the `Tweets` table and number of record should be added to the `Tweet_contain` table depending on how many of the team twitter usernames in the tweet text. This is where the issue is. Since the tweet only should be added once and the relation between team and tweet can be added several times in `Tweet_contain` it creates an issue. This is due to the fact that the `$last_id` will return 0 since the `$teamQuery` is being looped?

```
function checkTweetsForTeams($text, $created, $twitterId, $favoriteCount) {
    global $con;

    $ids = getTeams();

    foreach($ids as $id => $teams) {
        foreach($teams as $team) {

            if(stripos($text, $team) !== false) {

                $teamRelation = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO tweets(`created`, `twitterId`, `favoriteCount`) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tweets.favoriteCount = ?");
                $teamRelation->bind_param("ssii", $created, $twitterId, $favoriteCount, $favoriteCount);
                $teamRelation->execute();
                $last_id = $con->insert_id;
                $teamRelation->close();

                $tweetRelation = $con->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO tweet_contain (`tweetId`, `teamId`) VALUES (?, ?)");
                $tweetRelation->bind_param("ii", $last_id, $id);
                $tweetRelation->execute();
                $tweetRelation->close();

            }
        }
    }
}
```